# CSS transition ease-in-out does not work

Tags: html, css

I added transition ease-in-out in CSS. When user click menus in container 3, articles in container 2 shows and when it shows, it moves up and down smoothly. For now, other tags are perfectly work fine except transition. Which part should I have to fix?

```css
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 70%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    float:right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
  
#container3{
    width: 25%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 /*responsive image*/
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.panel{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;  
}

a[ id= "one" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "two" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}

a[ id= "commerce" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
    transform: translateY( -1000px );
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="container3">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#commerce">Commerce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#one"> 1 </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#two"> 2 </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#two"> 2 </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#two"> 2 </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
       
    <div id="container2">

        <article class="panel" id="one">
            <h1> A bit of text here</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="panel" id="two">
            <h1> More here :-)</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="panel" id="commerce"><img src = "http://plusquotes.com/images/quotes-img/roundflower.jpg" alt="breakfast"></article>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just do transform not -webkit-transform

Comment: You can't make scroll animation with css. Here it's just HTML anchor who scroll the page. Use JavaScript or JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** create a **scroll animation** with **CSS**.

In your example, the animation is just done with **HTML anchor**.

But you can use `JavaScript/JQuery` for that.

**Example**

```js
function scrollToAnchor(id){
    var element = $("#"+id);
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top},'slow');
}
```

```css
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:800px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border:solid 1px #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="scrollToAnchor('1')">nav 1</a>
<a onclick="scrollToAnchor('2')">nav 2</a>
<a onclick="scrollToAnchor('3')">nav 3</a>
<div class="content" id="1">1</div>
<div class="content" id="2">2</div>
<div class="content" id="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet, but I wanted to improve **Alexis** his answer.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', 'a[href^="#"]', function( e ) {
    var _this = jQuery( this ), _target = jQuery( _this.attr( 'href' ) );

    if ( _target.length ) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var offset = _target.offset().top - (parseInt( _this.data( 'offset' ) ) || 100), v_offset = jQuery( document ).height() - jQuery( window ).height() - 100, speed = Math.abs( jQuery( window ).scrollTop() - offset );

         jQuery( 'html, body' ).animate( {
             scrollTop : offset <= v_offset ? offset : v_offset
        }, (Math.log( Math.pow( speed / 1000, .5 ) ) + 1) * 1000 );
    }
} );
```

By using this on click event all of the anchor tags which use the # will use the animate function. By doing it this way you won't have to use an onclick on every single link :)

```
<a href="#example" offset="300">Testing</a>
```

You can use a different **offset** for each internal link. As used in the code above the standard offset is 100px.